# User Tweets Stream Twitter

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-oauth

Twitter API has the [GET method](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) that return specific user tweets,
I want to create `stream` by specific user, but in Twitter Stream API there no method that can help me.

`GET Sites in Beta now, I haven't got access to it`

Any Idea how to create live update/stream with specific twitter user ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 solutions. If you are able to get the credentials from the user (user accepting your app), then you can use the [UserStream](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams).

If you do not have access to this, you will have to use the [FilterStream](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter).

This one is a bit more restrictive as you cannot run more than 2 FilteredStream from the same ip or with the same credentials. In addition to this, a FilteredStream is limited to 5000 users as described on the twitter doc.

> The default access level allows up to 400 track keywords, 5,000 follow userids and 25 0.1-360 degree location boxes.

Comment: 1 solution - not my way.
2 solution - return all tweets where user name was mentioned, I need only his tweets

Comment: These are the 2 only solutions you will be able to use, so I would suggest that you filter down the results from the FilteredStream.

Comment: you suggest to filter [this follow method](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#follow) by first option `Tweets created by the user.` ?

Comment: I suggest that you get all the tweets from the `FilteredStream` and you check if any of the user you want to follow is the actual author of the tweet (not only a mention). You can find the author of a tweet in the `user` json property.

Comment: Ok, that was very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution to this problem is to use follow IDs within your stream and then check that the tweet->user->id for each tweet is within the list of follow IDs. That way you know that the post is original and not being retweeted etc. It does seem bizarre that twitter doesn't allow you to filter only messages "from".

I also believe that retweets have an 'retweeted_status' element in the result which if absent also shows its a new tweet from your following User IDs.